# GDAL C++ test layer capabilities

Tags: gdal, c++

I'm trying to check if a shapefile has the fast feature count.
I have the following C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ogrsf_frmts.h"

int main()
{
    GDALAllRegister();
    GDALDataset *poDS;
    poDS = (GDALDataset*)GDALOpenEx("C:/Users/root/Desktop/2016/GIS Programming/Plugin_new_new/Shapefiles_Karte/Ortsstrasse/temp/buildings - Kopie (2).shp", GDAL_OF_VECTOR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (poDS == NULL)
    {
        printf("Open failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (poDS->TestCapability(OLCFastFeatureCount) == true) {
        printf("true\n");
    } else {
        printf("false\n");
    }

    GDALClose(poDS);
}
```

The code tells me every time "false" even though I am 100% sure the input shapefile has the fast feature count ability.

So I assume that there is a problem in the function call. Isn't this the way you call the TestCapability function?

I am very new to C++ and have only used GDAL with Python so far ..

Comment: I answered below, but it was sloppy.  The layers of a shape datasource support fast feature count (in some cases), but the datasource doesn't.  Read more about the OGR data model if you are unclear on the distinction.  Your answer below shows this more than mine, so I'll just drop mine

Answer (score 1):

Ok, by looking at the source code of a python script doing the exact same thing I think I found the error.
The working source code is this one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ogrsf_frmts.h"

int main()
{
    GDALAllRegister();
    GDALDataset *poDS;    
    poDS = (GDALDataset*)GDALOpenEx("C:/Users/root/Desktop/2016/GIS Programming/Plugin_new_new/Shapefiles_Karte/Landkreise/Landkreise.shp", GDAL_OF_VECTOR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (poDS == NULL)
    {
        printf("Open failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    bool fastFeatureCount = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < poDS->GetLayerCount(); i++){
       auto layer = poDS->GetLayer(i);
       if (layer->TestCapability(OLCFastFeatureCount) == false) fastFeatureCount = false;
    }

    printf("%d\n", fastFeatureCount);


    GDALClose(poDS);
}
```

Might be some sloppy coding style in there, but I'm new to c++ and don't know any better ..

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
    if (poDS->TestCapability(OLCFastFeatureCount) == true) {
```

This is dangerous: `TestCapability` returns an `int`, which is documented to be `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Comparing an `int` to the boolean value `true` will cause the boolean to be implicitly converted to 1, so if `TRUE` is defined as `-1` or some other value, you'll get `false` from this comparison.

Instead you should compare to the constant `TRUE`:

```cpp
    if (poDS->TestCapability(OLCFastFeatureCount) == TRUE) {
```

Or just check for nonzero (because any sane library defines `FALSE` as 0):

```cpp
    if (poDS->TestCapability(OLCFastFeatureCount)) {
```